# IOS: textfield and double value

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, double

I have this situation:

I should write in a text field a value in euro.
If inside this text field I write "10" I should store in a double value "10.00" or if I write "10,1" I should store in a double "10,10" or if I write "10,23" I should store "10,23"

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should help:

`double val = [[textField text] doubleValue];`

Comment: ok and if inside textfield I write "10.23" or "10,23" is the same thing? What's the difference?

Comment: Damns, I don't noticed that comma. Ok you may use different construction which will remove **comma** occurrence in string to **dot** (this will be ok, if this field used only for number input) `double val = [[[textField text] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."] doubleValue];`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support localized numbers (e. g. user input), `-[NSNumberFormatter numberFromString:]` is the way to go. Since this returns an `NSNumber` you can get the double value using `-[NSNumber doubleValue]`:

```
NSNumber *number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:inputString];
double doubleValue = [number doubleValue];
```

Comment: this is the propper way to do it, not the marked answer! (1up)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the typecasting like convert string to double value.

Comment: No, typecasting won’t work – neither casting to a `double` nor to an `NSNumber`.